# Laravel-echo-server: how to listen to user leaving a channel

Tags: laravel, socket.io, socket.io-redis, laravel-echo

I've been fiddling a lot lately with Laravel Echo and Laravel Echo Server, a socket.io server implementation for Laravel Echo.

There's not much on the web, and I'm probably missing some point..

I can see from the cli of laravel-echo-server when a user joins or leaves a channel (presence channel in my case).
I have a Laravel Event that performs some DB operations that I want to fire when a user leaves a presence channel. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
Echo.join(`chat.${roomId}`)
    .here((users) => {
        //
    })
    .joining((user) => {
        console.log(user.name);
    })
    .leaving((user) => {
        console.log(user.name);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel Echo, you can listen to a user joining or leaving a channel using the `joining` and `leaving` methods respectively. Here's how you can do it:

```js
Echo.join(`chat.${roomId}`)
    .here((users) => {
        // This is triggered when the current user joins the channel
    })
    .joining((user) => {
        // This is triggered when any user joins the channel
        console.log(user.name);
    })
    .leaving((user) => {
        // This is triggered when any user leaves the channel
        console.log(user.name);
    });
```

In this example, replace `roomId` with the ID of your room. The `joining` and `leaving` methods will log the name of the user who joined or left the channel.